# Why add "ei" to a sentence with "imperare" and "parere"?

Tags: translation-explanation, relative-clause, demonstrative-pronoun

In North & Hillard, Ex. 20, Q. 2, the student is invited to translate this sentence into Latin:

> Those who wish to command ought to learn to obey.

I gave this translation: *qui imperare volunt discere parere debent.*

The answer book says this is correct except that the word *ei* should be included.

I know that *imperare* and *parere[2]* take the dative case; but I thought that, here, both verbs are intransitive?
Does the answer given mean to command or to obey "him"?

Is the inclusion of *ei* mandatory; would the sentence be correct without it?

Comment: **Ei** here is nom. pl. (translating 'those' which is an emphatic 'they') rather than the dative, I would think.

Comment: As Hugh notes, ei is nom.pl. Although I wouldn't say it's strictly mandatory here, I personally would put it in just to break up that string of 5 consecutive verb forms: qui imperare volunt, ei parere discere debent.

Comment: _eī_ (the later form of *iī*) is indeed completely superfluous there.

Answer (score 3):

The relative pronoun *qui* is masculine plural, and you translate it as "those who". As you can see, in English, we have a demonstrative/personal pronoun "those" and a relative pronoun "who". In Latin (and some other languages), the demonstrative pronoun can be left out in certain such cases. You have left it out.

I think that's acceptable, but you could add the Latin pronoun, representing English "those". That pronoun would be *ei*, which is masculine plural, and nominative, because it is the subject of the main clause (...*debent*).

Note that this construction has nothing to do with indirect speech.